# Moving logic from the view to a custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I created a Knockout extender so I can easily revert my form fields to their original values.

I want to cut out the clutter from my view so I want to transform this:

```
<div data-bind="if: myObservedValue.hasChanges">
  <a href="#" data-bind="click: myObservedValue.revert">Revert</a>
</div>
```

Into something like this:

```
  <a href="#" data-bind="revert: myObservedValue">Revert</a>
```

I know that I need to create a custom binding but I'm struggling to find a clean way to:

1. Only pass my observable to my binding and apply the visible binding internally (considering whether or not my observable extension hasChanges)
2. Combine multiple bindings since my 'revert' binding will need to use the 'click' and 'visible' bindings
3. Avoid exposing the revert function to my view

Thanks in advance

```js
ko.extenders.revert = function(target, option) {
  target.revert = function() {
    target(target.previousValue);
    target.hasChanges(false);
  };

  target.previousValue = option;
  target.hasChanges = ko.observable(false);
  target.hasChanges.extend({
    rateLimit: 100
  });
  target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    target.hasChanges(target() != target.previousValue);
  });
  return target;
};

var Vm = function(initialValue) {
  this.myObservedValue = ko.observable(initialValue).extend({
    revert: initialValue
  });
  this.revert = function() {
    this.revert();
  }.bind(this.myObservedValue);

  return {
    myObservedValue: this.myObservedValue,
    revert: this.revert
  }

}

ko.applyBindings(new Vm('Edit me!!!'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="textInput: myObservedValue" />
<div data-bind="if: myObservedValue.hasChanges">
  <a href="#" data-bind="click: myObservedValue.revert">Revert</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the applyBindingsToNode function to wrap other bindings

```js
ko.extenders.revert = function(target, option) {
  target.revert = function() {
    target(target.previousValue);
    target.hasChanges(false);
  };

  target.previousValue = option;
  target.hasChanges = ko.observable(false);
  target.hasChanges.extend({
    rateLimit: 100
  });
  target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    target.hasChanges(target() != target.previousValue);
  });
  return target;
};

var Vm = function(initialValue) {
  this.myObservedValue = ko.observable(initialValue).extend({
    revert: initialValue
  });
  this.revert = function() {
    this.revert();
  }.bind(this.myObservedValue);

  return {
    myObservedValue: this.myObservedValue,
    revert: this.revert
  }

}

ko.bindingHandlers["revert"] = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var obs = valueAccessor();
    
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { visible: obs.hasChanges, click: obs.revert });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Vm('Edit me!!!'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="textInput: myObservedValue" />
<a href="#" data-bind="revert: myObservedValue">Revert</a>
```

It is possible to get rid of the anchor all together by wrapping the textInput bindings as well

```js
var oldTextInputInit = ko.bindingHandlers["textInput"].init;

ko.bindingHandlers["textInput"].init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  
  var obs = valueAccessor();

  if (obs.revert && obs.hasChanges) {
    var a = element.ownerDocument.createElement('a');
    a.href = '#';

    if ( element.nextSibling ) {
      element.parentNode.insertBefore(a, element.nextSibling);
    } else {
      element.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    }

    ko.applyBindingsToNode( a, { text: 'Revert', visible: obs.hasChanges, click: obs.revert });
  }
  return oldTextInputInit(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
}
```

You could also added another custom binding to the input that is read by the overridden textInput binding so you could passing a template name to control the additional HTML to be added, etc

Comment: Thank you Robert. I've also found a video from Ryan Niemeyer about the preprocessing mechanism that apparently can simplify the syntax: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kep19WW7rp8#t=326